# Getting error code from MongoWriteException, duplicate key error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to detect duplicate a key insertion error in my code written by means of C# and MongoDB.Driver.

Is it correct error handling for this case? (there is a unique index on EntityId column)

```
    public class Entity
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string EntityId { get; set; }
    }

    ...

    public async Task<string> CreateEntityAsync(string entityId)
    {

        var entity = new Entity
        {
            EntityId = entityId,
        };
        try
        {
            await Collection.InsertOneAsync(peer);
        }
        //according to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique error 11000 should be raised.
        catch (MongoWriteException ex) when (GetErrorCode(ex) == 11000)
        {
            //custom error handling
        }
        return entity.Id;
    }

    private int GetErrorCode(MongoWriteException ex)
    {
        return (ex.InnerException as MongoBulkWriteException)?.WriteErrors.FirstOrDefault()?.Code ?? 0;
    }
```

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: You should probably right tests for your code.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner code would be to catch `MongoWriteException` and filter with [when](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when) by the Category, example code:

```
try {
  await _collection.InsertOneAsync(playerIn);
} catch (MongoWriteException ex) when (ex.WriteError.Category == ServerErrorCategory.DuplicateKey) {
  // Custom error handling
}
```